# Copy site contents using Get-PnPSiteTemplate

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I can extract a site structure using **Get-PnPSiteTemplate** but this doesnt copy the content.  How can I create a template with content?

I've seen use of the **-scope** option when using **get-PnpSiteTemplate** but a) I dont know if this would let be obtain content and b) if it does, I dont know how to create the JSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PnP templates only contain limited amounts of site content. This content will sometimes be branding files, in order to create the same look and feel as the site from which the template was created. To do this, the template needs to be exported as a `.pnp` file.

If you would like a specific set of files to be copied to a site after applying a site template, you could use the various PnP cmdlets for copying content e.g. Copy-PnPFile, Copy-PnPFolder.

Comment: I've managed to copy over site content in terms of items in the Site Asset Library by using a -Configuration (not -scope!) set to   "persistAssetFiles": true.  This worked leaving the template in XML.  Do you know what a PNP template covers that an XML one doesnt? Thanks!